# jQuery UI date picker - updating another date picker on selecting a date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have 2 date pickers using the Jquery UI. If the user selects a date from date picker 1, how can I get it to update date picker 2 automatically with the same date?

I think this might be quite simple, but I've tried a few things and nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date picker is essentially a text input element.  You can use the jquery change handler on the first input element to grab its contents when they change, then simply select the second input element and update the value using jquery val.

http://api.jquery.com/change/
http://api.jquery.com/val/

Something like:

```
$("#firstdatepicker").change(  function() {
   $("#seconddatepicker").val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I tried doing something similar but didn't realise I would need to nest my functions.

Comment: @mcot this is cool! how to add +7 days on second input and disable days after that date?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the [onClose](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onClose) event to  update the second text field.

I've created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hu8Pm/) here that works; for some reason the styling that's usually on the datepicker is not coming in though.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="date1" value="" />
<br>
<input type="text" name="date2" value="" />
```

Javascript:

```
$("input[name=date1]").datepicker({
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        $("input[name=date2]").val(dateText);
    }
});
$("input[name=date2]").datepicker();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I chose the other answer simply because it did the same thing with less code.

Comment: I hear that - I use the events a plugin gives me because I like to keep all my functionality bundled together