# How to display age based on dob in html javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In the code below, how do I display age based on date of birth into a text box. When I am trying outside it's working in normal. How to write onchange() based on date of birth?

This is sample code.Can any one help me from this issue

**html**

```
<input type="text" name="date_birth1"   class="login-input" placeholder="Date Of Birth" id="datepicker1" autofocus>
   <input type="text" name="age" id="age" pattern = "^\D{0,100}$"  class="login-input" placeholder="Age" autofocus >
```

**javascript**

```
<script>

        $(function() {

            $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }).val()

        });
        $(function() {

            $("#datepicker1").datepicker();

        });
        $(function() {

            $("#datepicker2").datepicker();

        });
        $(function() {

            $("#datepicker3").datepicker();

        });
        $(function() {

            $("#datepicker4").datepicker();

        });
        $(function() {

            $("#datepicker5").datepicker();

        });
        $(function() {

            $("#datepicker6").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }).val()

        });
    $(function() {
        $('#datepicker1').datepicker({

        onSelect: function(value, ui) {
            var today = new Date(), 
                dob = new Date(value), 
                age = new Date(today - dob).getFullYear() - 1970;

            $('#age').text(age);
        },
        maxDate: '+0d',
        yearRange: '1920:2010',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
    });
        </script>
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having, specifically?

Comment: Also, I've made an edit to the question text to make it more clear what you're asking; if that is not what you are asking, go ahead and rollback or update the edit.

Comment: @PaulRichter when I am selecting the date of birth i want to show age in my age input field without entering anything

Comment: Ok, well Kushal's code should do that for you. You can also use datepicker's [`onClose`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8619085/877472), alternatively.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for onchange event to be fired on datepicker then check it out here [jQuery trigger a DatePicker change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919563/jquery-trigger-a-datepicker-change-event)

Edit:

```
$("#datepicker6").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" })
.on("change", function(){
    // do whatever you want to`
})
```

Comment: without onchage it is possible?

Comment: Do you want the DOB to be fetched when the user interacts with it or not?

Comment: I think so then using onchange is a better way of doing it .. by the way whats the problem in using it?